# Parsed elements coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following JSON:

```
{
"customers": [
{ "name":"joe" , "cars":[
    {"name":"honda","visits":[
        {"date":"01/30/14","Id":"201"},
        {"date":"01/30/14","Id":"201"},
        {"date":"02/12/14","Id":"109"}
        ]},
         {"name":"Nissan","visits":[
        {"date":"01/30/14","Id":"201"},
        {"date":"02/12/14","Id":"109"}
        ]}
    ]},

{ "name":"bob" , "cars":[
    {"name":"escalade","visits":[
         {"date":"01/05/14","Id":"301"},
        {"date":"01/18/14","Id":"551"}
        ]},
         {"name":"corvette","visits":[
         {"date":"01/05/14","Id":"301"},
        {"date":"01/18/14","Id":"551"}
        ]}
    ]} 
]
}
```

Using the following jQuery script:

```
$("document").ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("data1.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console

            $.each(json.customers,function(customer){
        console.log(customer.name);
        console.log(customer.cars);     
    });
});

});
```

The JSON is coming through in the console but the fields I'm trying to parse are coming up as undefined. Can anyone ell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `customer` is the index of the object in the array. The object is passed as second argument. See the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. Putting `console.log(customer)` inside the callback helps to debug the problem.

Comment: `console.log(this.name)` and `console.log(this.cars)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is your usage of [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), your callback function will receive the index as the first argument and the value as the second argument and it looks like you are expecting the first argument to be the value.  So in your current code `customer` will be an index (`0`, `1`, etc.) rather than the object from your JSON.

Try changing your `$.each` call to the following:

```
$.each(json.customers, function(index, customer) {
    console.log(customer.name);
    console.log(customer.cars);     
});
```